# Multiple choice window in zenity

Tags: bash, user-interface, zenity

How to add buttons in zenity in order to make a multiple choice question? Something like:

```
zenity --info \
--title="Super Quizz" \
--text="Who is Mark Zuckerberg?" \
--add-button="A soccer player" \
--add-button="An astronaut" \
--add-button="An internet entrepreneur" \
--add-button="I don't know"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best option is to use a [radio list](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/list.html.en) instead:

```
zenity --list \
--title="Super Quizz" \
--text "Who is Mark Zuckerberg?" \
--radiolist \
--column "Pick" \
--column "Answer" \
FALSE "A soccer player" \
FALSE "An astronaut" \
FALSE "An internet entrepreneur" \
FALSE "I don't know"
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Zenity have an `--extra-button` option. Use `--question` with `--switch` to suppress the default OK/Cancel buttons:

```
zenity --question \
  --switch \
  --title="Super Quizz" \
  --text="Who is Mark Zuckerberg?" \
  --extra-button="A soccer player" \
  --extra-button="An astronaut" \
  --extra-button="An internet entrepreneur" \
  --extra-button="I don't know"
```

[image: Screenshot of question dialog showing quiz]